# Correct pronunciation of `vi` (Unix editor)?

Tags: unix, terminology, editor

According to [this video with Brian Kernighan](https://youtu.be/NTfOnGZUZDk?t=115), the correct pronunciation of the classical Unix editor `ed` is "Eee. Dee." — not "Edd".

So that made me wonder — what about the other classical editor, `vi`... should it be pronounced as "Vee. Aye." or as "Viii"?  Does anybody know?

(I'm ignoring `vim` for this discussion — I suppose it is simply "Viimm".)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135357/discussion-on-question-by-baard-kopperud-correct-pronunciation-of-vi-unix-edi).

Comment: I have heard people pronounce it 'six', and claim it is its version number, and at the time roman numerals were still used.

Comment: @Aganju You say that there was any significant decline or Roman numeral since the advent of the vi editor?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава The joke is that vi is so old the Romans were using it.

Comment: @Chenmunka: The first comment from Jean​‑François Fabre's joke comment wasn't "extended discussion", and was the best part about this whole Q&A.  Please restore it.  Especially since others have made the same "six" comment (as a non-joke?).

Comment: Why have two people voted to close this question as "opinion based". Since two answers have been given referencing the official way to pronounce "vi", it clearly isn't opinion based.

Comment: @JeremyP For a radical descriptivist, this doesn’t matter, since a coiner of a term has no more authority over how it is supposed to be used than anyone else.

Comment: @user3840170 If you basically invents a word to name a program or a company, I would think you can decide what's the correct pronunciation too.  If the author decided that one pronunciation is the correct one, then that pronunciation is the program's name, while any other pronunciations simply aren't.

Comment: To a descriptivist, speaking of an objectively correct pronunciation is just as absurd as speaking of the objective worth of a currency. Saying a word is objectively correct to pronounce a certain way, because the one to create it said so, is just as absurd as saying that a coin is objectively worth a million dollars because the one who minted it said so. (I am not a descriptivist nearly that radical, but I can appreciate the position at least.)

Comment: I am so old that I remember that (on BSD), you could invoke vi with its full proper name: "visual" (but the shorter "vi" worked as well, so no one used "visual"). That was probably before the rise of the Roman empire. -- Note that only one of the two preceding sentences is a joke.

Comment: @Klaws I have of course heard of the VISUAL and EDITOR environment variable which would be set to `vi` and `ed` ...  Didn't know you could start it with `visual` though.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`vi` is pronounced as the two separate letters, /ˌviːˈaɪ/ (in English); listen [to the same Brian Kernighan](https://youtu.be/bSaBe6WiC2s) (also re-confirming the `ed` pronunciation).

Vim’s pronunciation is [explicitly documented](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html):

> Vim is pronounced as one word, like Jim, not vi-ai-em.

[Nemo](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/23974/nemo) mentioned [this interesting email about “Unix-room” pronunciations from Rob Pike](https://minnie.tuhs.org/pipermail/tuhs/2020-February/020257.html), which includes a number of interesting tidbits in relation to this question:

- some Unix-room denizens did pronounce `ed` like the first syllable of “editor”;
- `vi` was little-used but apparently pronounced /ˌviːˈaɪ/ by all its users;
- on Plan 9, `vi` was [a MIPS interpreter](http://man.cat-v.org/plan_9/1/vi) (“v” for MIPS, along with “5” for ARM, “k” for SPARC, and “q” for PowerPC), also pronounced /ˌviːˈaɪ/.

Note that `vi` came from BSD, not the Unix room, so Unix-room pronunciation isn’t necessarily canonical (if there is such a thing anyway in a living language). But [Mark Plotnick’s answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24271/79) gives a reference from `vi`’s creators themselves.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135401/discussion-on-answer-by-stephen-kitt-correct-pronunciation-of-vi-unix-editor).

Answer (score 25):

From [An Introduction to Display Editing with Vi](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4BSD/usr/doc/ex/vi.in), by the people who wrote vi, William Joy and
Mary Ann Horton:

> This document provides a quick introduction to
> *vi.* (Pronounced *vee-eye*.)

Comment: That first author's name surprised me.  I knew that _Bill Joy_ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Joy) had put together the first cut of vi.  Then it struck me that _William Joy_ and _Bill Joy_ were likely the same person